# unable to install ubuntu 18.04 blank display

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, usb-installation, amd-ryzen

1. used rufus-4.0 to flash my external hard disk with ubuntu 18.04 downloaded from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/). In rufus I
   selected dd image option. (I had tried the ISO image mode with balenaEtcher)
2. Disabled Windows Secure Boot in BIOS and Fast Mode in Windows 11
3. pressed F12, selected External Hard Disk, when 'Install Ubuntu' option came pressed 'e' , found Linux and tried

   - 'nomodeset' at the end as well as
   - 'no quiet splash' as well as
   - 'acpi = off' and
   - 'nolapic'

tried [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Also changed graphics in BIOS from discrete graphics to dynamic graphics

I still get a blank screen.

Edit 1: Installation didn't begin. No Ubuntu logo appears, and no language options are displayed. I am trying Ubuntu 18.04 for a specific reason. If it doesn't work, then shall try 20.04. please let me know if you need any more information.

Edit 2: I tried installing 20.04.6 desktop amd64 and was able to install it. Probably the issue was with my drivers and ubuntu 18.04. Thanks for your support.

Specs:
- Here are the specs for the

- Lenovo Legion 5:
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics
- BIOS Mode: UEFI
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, with driver version 512.36.Windows 11 (nvidia settings show Windows 10 Home, 64-bit)

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the 2018-April release (the *year.month* format makes that easy to remember) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life; ie. it's very soon to end, and will be off-topic once the EOSS (*end of standard support* notices come out). Why try and install a release that can only be used for *hours/days*?  Why not use a more modern system than one about to EOSS?

Comment: You should have used ISO mode with Rufus. Your question is not clear did the install finish with no errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)